# PHP Undefined Offset unless printed out

Tags: php, arrays, undefined, offset

While trying to read data from a socket ran the following code through the interpreter:

```
function get_song_title($stream){
    $song;
    $sc_return = array();
    $sc_return = explode("\r\n",$stream);
    $song = $sc_return[4];
    return $song;
}
```

This will succeed in getting the information I need 20% of the time maybe.

However when I do:

```
function get_song_title($stream){
    $song;
    $sc_return = array();
    $sc_return = explode("\r\n",$stream);
    echo $sc_return[4];
    $song = $sc_return[4];
    return $song;
}
```

it will succeed 100% of the time. Any method to print the array(or its elements) out will make it to work without a problem. If I simply to try return it or assign it the undefined offset 4 message comes up.

this also includes using print_r($sc_return); which will always succeed.

Any ideas why I would need to print the array element out for it to succeed all the time?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about why you need echo / print out to work, but...

try to do

```
var_dump($sc_rturn);
```

to see what you are getting.

also to check for undefined index, you should do

```
isset($sc_return[4]);
```

also you can count your results using

```
count($sc_return);
```

Comment: As said in the question: it is not so much about wether IF the element exists, it always exists apparently but the problem seems to be when you echo the element and then return it it works always but when you return it without echoing it first it only sometimes works

Comment: I tried all of that as per other PHP undefined offset error posts on stackoverflow. However, without a print it will error with isset() and var_dump() 80% of the time still.

Comment: Just to note, if you explode a string "ABCDEFG" without \r\n, you will get get back and array with a single value in it. Is there any function that is using the return value that is failing? can you add an additional check? if (count($sc_return) < 5) error_log('array too small',3,'my_error.log');

Comment: If explode returned a single value it wouldn't print out the 4th offset after the echo it would continually return an undefined offset.  This would also cause print_r to print out a single element.

Comment: explode will return an array with 1 element, yes, but i am still puzzled on the echo fixing things...

Comment: So what you are saying is an array requires an CRLF to explode?

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe $stream is a string input that is composed of CRLF, and you are trying to get the elements, if you pass in something like "ABC", you will end up as a result of explode, Array( [0] => "ABC"), if input is empty string "", explode will return FALSE, from here on, you need to do error checking with the results before proceeding further.